# How do I compose a model of a table and an "extension table"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to determine the best solution for composing a singular model of two separate tables-- the plain/standard table and an "extension table."

The following is a contrived example to (*hopefully*) help better illustrate:

**Tables:**

- **`users`**: `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`
- **`users_extend`**: `user_id`, `extra_field_1`, `extra_field_2`, `etc`

**Model:**

`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `extra_field_1`, `extra_field_2`, `etc`

I'm unable to alter the existing database structure, so whatever solution I use must be able to handle this type of setup.

The reason for the `_extend` table is so that downstream consumers of the application can add additional fields to the extension table without risk of damage to the `users` table with any future updates.

I've previously been pointed in the direction of `composed_of` as being a potential solution to this, but I can't see how it would resolve the issue of two connected tables. I also saw that it is still potentially subject  to deprecation/removal, so I think that path is likely ruled out.

Is single table inheritance a possible solution? It seems like something that could help, but I don't fully grasp how I could bend it to suit the problem I'm trying to solve.

Any help/examples at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TK-421 pointed out you'll need to set up a `has_one` association with `UserExtend`. Then you could use delegation for the needed attributes. Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  USER_EXTEND_ATTRS = %i(extra_field_1 extra_field_2).freeze

  has_one :user_extend
  delegate *USER_EXTEND_ATTRS, to: :user_extend
end
```

Answer (score 3):

`User` can simply `has_one` `UserExtend` (or perhaps a more consistent name like `UserExtension`), which can `belongs_to` `User`.

You can probably get more fancy with this, but it seems logical because `users_extend` already has the conventional `user_id` foreign key.

Your specific implementation may change this, but it seems feasible based on the description.